# Can't upload video in shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

i need to add video in the product gallery .For this i am going through this tutorial https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-theme-support-for-rich-media-3d-and-video

But when i add this code The product image is disappeared and the video is not uploaded also.

I am use this code in Product template and media below.

```html
   // Product-template
 {% for media in product.media %}
      {% include 'media' %}
    {% endfor %}

//In midea

    {% case media.media_type %}
      {% when 'image' %} 
            <div class="thumb">
              <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="{{ image.src | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" >
                <img id="product-featured-image-{{image.id}}" class="product-featured-img" src="{{ image | img_url: 'original' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-zoom-image="{{ image.src | img_url: 'original' }}"/>
              </a>
            </div>
{% when 'external_video' %}
        <div class="product-single__media" style="padding-top: {{ 1 | divided_by: media.aspect_ratio | times: 100}}%;" data-media-id="{{ media.id }}">
          {{ media | external_video_tag }}
        </div>
      {% when 'video' %}
        <div class="product-single__media" data-media-id="{{ media.id }}">
          {{ media | video_tag: controls: true }}
        </div>
      {% when 'model' %}
        <div class="product-single__media" style="padding-top: 100%" data-media-id="{{ media.id }}">
          {{ media | model_viewer_tag }}
        </div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="product-single__media" style="padding-top: 100%;" data-media-id="{{ media.id }}">
          {{ media | media_tag }}
        </div>
    {% endcase %}
```

Comment: The snippet does not work. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Product.media and product images are different objects.

```
{% for media in product.media %}
    {% if media.media_type == 'video' %}
        {{ media | video_tag: controls: true, preload: true, image_size: "1024x" }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}       
{% for image in product.images %}
        {% if forloop.first == true %}
    <figure>            
        <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" class="product_variant_image">
    </figure>
        {% else %}
                    <figure>            
        <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
    </figure>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You need a mix of the two objects or add the photos you want to show it into media.